Python Sympy, partial fraction decomposition: result not as expected
I am using the Python library Sympy to calculate the partial fraction decomposition of the following rational function:
Z = (6.43369157032015e-9*s^3 + 1.35203404799555e-5*s^2 + 0.00357538393743079*s + 0.085)/(4.74334912634438e-11*s^4 + 4.09576274286244e-6*s^3 + 0.00334241812250921*s^2 + 0.15406018058983*s + 1.0)
I am calling the method apart() like this:
Z_f = apart(Z, full=True).doit()
And this is the result:
-1.30434068814287e+23/(s + 85524.0054884464) + 19145168.0/(s + 774.88576677949) + 91.9375/(s + 40.7977016133126) + 2.59375/(s + 7.79746609204661)

As you can see from the result, these are the residuals:

-3.60418953263334e+22
-4789228.25000000
11.0468750000000
0.787109375000000

Note: I identify them like this:
Z_f_terms = Z_f.as_ordered_terms()

and then extract them in a for cycle.
The problem is that by using other tools I get different residuals.
By using GNU Octave's residue() I get these residuals:

133.6
1.0776
0.39501
0.56426

Via Wolphram Alpha I get the same residuals as Octave see here the results (please wait until you see the partial fraction expansion) .
Why isn't the Sympy library not working as expected?
The poles are always correct. Only the residuals are not as I expect.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Could you explain how you identify the residuals you have quoted from the partial fraction expansion that you given. BTW, if your roots are just simple poles then you can work out the top of the fractions from the “cover-up rule”.

why not use scipy.signal.residue?

@lastchance I use ".as_ordered_terms". Please see the updated question.

@Davide_sd
Thanks, I have just tried and it works. The only one case which doesn't work is Sympy. Can anyone reproduce this?

Yes, @JackSlater, I can reproduce your sympy problem. I also tried with a much simpler expression: Z = (12*s**2 - 44*s + 36)/(s**3-6*s**2+11*s-6). Watch what happens when you change that 12 (int) to 12.0 (float). I think the symbolic arithmetic of sympy is running into floating-point precision problems when you have terms of very different orders of magnitude (in your case coefficients from 1e-11 to 1.0). I would use @Davide_sd's suggestion rather than symbolic arithmetic. Or you can do as I did and find the roots with a polynomial class, then use the cover-up rule to find residuals.

Please show how you obtained the numbers you cited. Details missing in "extracted in a for cycle" and it is not obvious how the numbers you got relate to the terms from which the for loop extracted them.

@lastchance
Thank you, I tried both Davide_sd's suggestion and Oscar Benjamin's and the Scipy calculation seems faster.

@JackSlater it doesn't seem. It is! Use SymPy only if you really need a symbolic solution, otherwise it's better to use numerical libraries.

The problem is to do with floats. Presumably something in the algorithm used by apart(full=True) or RootSum.doit() is numerically unstable for approximate coefficients.
If you convert the coefficients to rational numbers before computing the RootSum then evalf gives the expected result:
In [27]: apart(nsimplify(Z), full=True).evalf()
Out[27]: 
  133.599202650992      1.07757928431867      0.395006955518971      0.564264854137341  
──────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ──────────────────── + ────────────────────
s + 85524.0054884464   s + 774.88576677949   s + 40.7977016133126   s + 7.79746609204661

In [29]: apart(Z, domain="QQ", full=True).evalf()  # rational field
Out[29]: 
  133.599202650994      1.07757928431867      0.395006955518971      0.564264854137341  
──────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ──────────────────── + ────────────────────
s + 85524.0054884464   s + 774.88576677949   s + 40.7977016133126   s + 7.79746609204661

Note that the general algorithm and approach used for full=True is really intended for finding an exact representation of the decomposition by avoiding radicals. It is not intended for floats. Probably though normal apart without full=True should compute this decomposition.

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/26648

Thank you for your detailed explaination, this indeed fixes the issue. I also tried "apart" without "full=True" and it doesn't work. I have no experience with this library, is this issue something that should be reported to the devs? By the way you should edit your answer like this: domain='QQ'.

You don't need to use domain='QQ' if you do from sympy import QQ. My answer is demonstrated in an isympy session which implicitly uses from sympy import *.

The original bug will be fixed in SymPy 1.13: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/26649

Thank you very much for opening the issue, fixing it and reporting back here very quickly. Much appreciated, congrats. Super!
